# How do I ensure the I & client's PCs always have the same IP address when we connect to MS SQL/MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have read the it is good security practice to restrict access to a database server by only allowing a pre-defined list/range of IP addresses. I don't know how to guarantee/ensure that my IP address remains the same because it is always assigned via DHCP. I imagine the same will be true for website visitors as well.

My projects usually have two types of users: company staff and the public. The company staff connect to the database via a MS Access front end while the public/customers will connect via web sites.

How do I implement the good practice of restricting the allowed IP Addresses while at the same time ensuring that everyone can connect?

Take IMDB or DHL for example. How do they get around this 'restriction' for their website visitors?

Because I don't know how to ensure this, I always set the MS SQL Server on Azure or AWS to allow all IP addresses. I have read that MySQL doesn't even allow this and so I haven't been able to use the free MySQL db hosting offered with most web hosting packages. There are some web hosts like HostGator that insist on connecting to the MySQL db as local host and even specify an IP address that must be used for connecting to the MySQL db. I don't know how to do all this. That's why I've been using MS SQL Server.

Comment: The application code for your website may be on the same server as your database server, or on a different (but dedicated) server. You should be able to assign a static ip to that webserver (application code server which then connects to database)

Comment: 2 devices won't have the same IP; having 2 with the same will only cause problems. if you mean access an external site, then the location (i.e. a business site) will likely have a single WAN IP, but every device in the domain will have a different, unique IP within that domain.

Comment: *"Take IMDB or DHL for example. How do they get around this 'restriction' for their website visitors?"* Simplified a little, their web server accepts connections from all IP addresses; their database server accepts connections only from the web server. People talk to the web server; the web server talks to the database server.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to guarantee/ensure that my IP address remains the same because it is always assigned via DHCP. I imagine the same will be true for website visitors as well.

Aside from IP restriction, do NOT expose all ports at SQL Server side, let only SQL Ports open, and limit users to be added in `Builtin\administrators` group of SQL Server.

It's hard to restrict client IP Address (even internal), instead you can configure VLAN so that only users part of that VLAN would be able to access database services. In your case Internal users and Web Server must be in same VLAN.

> How do I implement the good practice of restricting the allowed IP Addresses while at the same time ensuring that everyone can connect?

[You may want follow some of these best practices..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57399403/6598234)